# Trying to console.log properties from an Express/Mongo api, using a React.js frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, express, react-redux

I'm putting together a very simple fictional sneaker app, using the MERN stack.
I wouldn't call myself a newbie, but I'm not an expert either. I was able to create the backend just fine and generate a json rest-api. My problem is on the front-end. I'm simply trying to console.log a property from an object.

For example, I have a route that gets an array of sneaker objects. In each object, it contains info such as the Sneaker Model, Colorway, Year the sneaker was released, here a preview of the object.

```
{
    "_id": "5c5dff42489e28576c28cd9e",
    "model": "Air Jordan 11",
    "colorway": "Win Like 82",
    "year": 1997,
    "text": "Cool kicks",
    "mainimage": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549664062/xjwkpbqwl1pmawpocygx.jpg",
    "subimage_1": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549664062/y8h1biytup4rgxqrm2qe.jpg",
    "subimage_2": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549664063/wrwska4tnog4vselcwp7.jpg",
    "subimage_3": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549664063/h9dyki3gdgfjcccchhia.jpg",
    "subimage_4": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549664064/qwrsabomnsqk7pjyx5ss.jpg",
    "user": "5c4b4635c9de365620cd797b",
    "likes": [],
    "comments": [],
    "date": "2019-02-08T22:14:26.127Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I use destructuring to get the sneaker data from my application (Redux) state:
 `const { sneakers } = this.props.sneaker;`

When I try to console.log the array of objects using `console.log(sneakers)` it works as expected these are the results:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]


0:
colorway: "Win Like 82"
comments: []
date: "2019-02-08T22:14:26.127Z"
likes: []
mainimage: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549664062/xjwkpbqwl1pmawpocygx.jpg"
model: "Air Jordan 11"
subimage_1: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549664062/y8h1biytup4rgxqrm2qe.jpg"
subimage_2: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549664063/wrwska4tnog4vselcwp7.jpg"
subimage_3: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549664063/h9dyki3gdgfjcccchhia.jpg"
subimage_4: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549664064/qwrsabomnsqk7pjyx5ss.jpg"
text: "Cool kicks"
user: "5c4b4635c9de365620cd797b"
year: 1997
__v: 0
_id: "5c5dff42489e28576c28cd9e"
__proto__: Object


1:
colorway: "taxi"
comments: []
date: "2019-02-08T19:20:59.467Z"
likes: []
mainimage: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549653655/gag2aktdhyfru5s5dnni.jpg"
model: "Air Jordan 12"
subimage_1: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549653656/wcg9jmo84cl8mhxb2iwl.jpg"
subimage_2: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549653656/mxistpujhh0xikzqwcu0.jpg"
subimage_3: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549653657/dcp1y2jrqz2nkgyhuwfr.jpg"
subimage_4: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549653657/dyee9uzb7aj1dp46rlnj.jpg"
text: "the holy grails"
user: "5c4b4635c9de365620cd797b"
year: 1997
__v: 0
_id: "5c5dd69beaef7140e0d2926d"
__proto__: Object


2:
colorway: "Obsidian"
comments: []
date: "2019-02-03T23:01:21.937Z"
likes: []
mainimage: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549234878/yzdoot1cf3jnbq31ndkg.jpg"
model: "Air Jordan 12"
subimage_1: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549234879/jbjw8hngvieyvnizfb8b.jpg"
subimage_2: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549234880/qu1gguxpfp2mapd5ivo2.jpg"
subimage_3: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549234880/gcntdjlznjjbxifsmufl.jpg"
subimage_4: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549234881/ck9emeurmaqleizaqe1e.jpg"
text: "Awesome kicks"
user: "5c4b4553c9de365620cd797a"
year: 1997
__v: 0
_id: "5c5772c10ffd0f2e789999b2"
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

If I want to say for instance just the second sneaker I use:

`console.log(sneakers[1])`

I get what I expected:

```
{_id: "5c5dd69beaef7140e0d2926d", model: "Air Jordan 12", colorway: "taxi", year: 1997, text: "the holy grails", …}
colorway: "taxi"
comments: []
date: "2019-02-08T19:20:59.467Z"
likes: []
mainimage: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549653655/gag2aktdhyfru5s5dnni.jpg"
model: "Air Jordan 12"
subimage_1: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549653656/wcg9jmo84cl8mhxb2iwl.jpg"
subimage_2: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549653656/mxistpujhh0xikzqwcu0.jpg"
subimage_3: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549653657/dcp1y2jrqz2nkgyhuwfr.jpg"
subimage_4: "http://res.cloudinary.com/dwgjvssdt/image/upload/v1549653657/dyee9uzb7aj1dp46rlnj.jpg"
text: "the holy grails"
user: "5c4b4635c9de365620cd797b"
year: 1997
__v: 0
_id: "5c5dd69beaef7140e0d2926d"
__proto__: Object
```

However, when I try to get a property from just one sneaker, let's say for example the colorway from the second sneaker I use:

`console.log(sneakers[1].colorway)`

And I run into this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'colorway' of undefined`.

I'm a little hard pressed to figure out why. I figured since I can log data from one sneaker if I wanted to I should be able to log just one property from that sneaker. Obviously, there is something that I'm not doing quite right, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Thanks for posting the data examples, but can you post your code as well please?

Comment: His code is posted @MatthewHerbst, it's just a few `console.log` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the data object prints as a browser-level convenience but is not actually ready for property access. To circumvent this problem, I've used this pattern with success:

```
const SomeComponent = ({sneakers}) => {
  return (
    <div>
    {
      sneakers && sneakers.map(sneaker => {
        return (
          <div>{sneaker.colorway}</div>
        )
      })
    }
    </div>
  )
}

export default SomeComponent;
```